# FBX SDK - Texture scale and rotation not applied

Tags: c++, fbx

I'm adding a texture via a material to a mesh using the FBX SDK. Now I wonder why the texture scale is not applied - neither is the texture rotation. My source code looks as follows:

```
// Create texture
gTexture = FbxFileTexture::Create(gScene, "Diffuse Texture");
FbxString lTexPath = "C:\\Users\\padmalcom\\Crate.jpg";
gTexture->SetFileName(lTexPath.Buffer());
gTexture->SetTextureUse(FbxTexture::eStandard);
gTexture->SetMappingType(FbxTexture::eUV);
gTexture->SetMaterialUse(FbxFileTexture::eModelMaterial);
gTexture->SetSwapUV(false);
gTexture->SetTranslation(0.0, 0.0);
gTexture->SetScale(0.01, 0.01);
gTexture->SetRotation(45.0, 0.0);

// Create material
FbxString lMaterialName = "material";
FbxString lShadingName = "Phong";
FbxDouble3 lBlack(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
FbxDouble3 lRed(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
FbxDouble3 lDiffuseColor(0.75, 0.75, 0.0);
gMaterial = FbxSurfacePhong::Create(gScene, lMaterialName.Buffer());
gMaterial->Emissive.Set(lBlack); // Generate primary and secondary colors.
gMaterial->Ambient.Set(lRed);
gMaterial->Diffuse.Set(lDiffuseColor);
gMaterial->TransparencyFactor.Set(40.5);
gMaterial->ShadingModel.Set(lShadingName);
gMaterial->Shininess.Set(0.5);
```

Now the scale and rotation should be set but it is not. Any ideas?
[image: Missing rotation]

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the rotation and scaling values are actually set but the official Autodesk renderer (FBX Review) does not support them! Importing the model into Unreal Engine 4 results at least in the right texture scale so that I guess that there is no error in the code.